# using the NWS soap server with javax.xml.soap

Tags: java, xml, soap

I am trying to use the NWS soap server to get a lat/long points forecast.  I have tried several methods and the one I settled on uses javax.xml.soap.  The jax-ws method fails right away when I try: wsimport -keep http://graphical.weather.gov/xml/SOAP_server/ndfdXMLserver.php?wsdl.  I get an error indicating it can't handle encodeing.  This is the source I am working on now:

```
package soapexample;
import javax.xml.soap.*;

public class SoapExample {

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    // Create SOAP Connection
    SOAPConnectionFactory soapConnectionFactory = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
    SOAPConnection soapConnection = soapConnectionFactory.createConnection();

    // Send SOAP Message to SOAP Server
    String url = "http://graphical.weather.gov/xml/SOAP_server/ndfdXMLserver.php?wsdl";
    SOAPMessage soapResponse = soapConnection.call(createSOAPRequest(), url);

    // print SOAP Response
    System.out.print("Response SOAP Message:");
    soapResponse.writeTo(System.out);

    soapConnection.close();
}

private static SOAPMessage createSOAPRequest() throws Exception {
    MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
    SOAPMessage soapMessage = messageFactory.createMessage();
    SOAPPart soapPart = soapMessage.getSOAPPart();

    String serverURI = "http://www.weather.gov/";

    // SOAP Envelope
    SOAPEnvelope envelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();
    envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("xsi", serverURI);

    /*

    // SOAP Body
    SOAPBody soapBody = envelope.getBody();
    SOAPElement soapBodyElem = soapBody.addChildElement("NDFDgenByDay", "xsi");
    soapBody.setEncodingStyle("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/");
    SOAPElement soapBodyElem1 = soapBodyElem.addChildElement("startDate", "xsi");
    soapBodyElem1.addTextNode("2014-07-06");
    SOAPElement soapBodyElem2 = soapBodyElem.addChildElement("numDays", "xsi");
    soapBodyElem2.addTextNode("3");
    SOAPElement soapBodyElem3 = soapBodyElem.addChildElement("Unit", "xsi");
    soapBodyElem3.addTextNode("e");
    SOAPElement soapBodyElem4 = soapBodyElem.addChildElement("format", "xsi");
    soapBodyElem4.addTextNode("24 hourly");
    SOAPElement soapBodyElem5 = soapBodyElem.addChildElement("latitude", "xsi");
    soapBodyElem5.addTextNode("38.99");
    SOAPElement soapBodyElem6 = soapBodyElem.addChildElement("longitude", "xsi");
    soapBodyElem6.addTextNode("-77.01");
    soapMessage.saveChanges();

    /* Print the request message */
    System.out.print("Request SOAP Message:");
    soapMessage.writeTo(System.out);
    System.out.println();

    return soapMessage;
}
`
```

It almost works, I get this response:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<SOAP-ENV:Fault>
<faultcode xsi:type="xsd:string">SERVER</faultcode>
<faultactor xsi:type="xsd:string"></faultactor>
<faultstring xsi:type="xsd:string">format needs to be either 24 hourly or 12             hourly</faultstring>
<detail xsi:type="xsd:string">input format was &quot;-77.01&quot;</detail>
</SOAP-ENV:Fault>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
</code></pre>
```

I am lost at this point.  I can't find the problem with my  request.  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

After very little interest in my question I decided to google myself to death again and found an excellent article on why the National Weather Service does not work with JAX-WS.  They even provide a working example for using SAAJ instead.  The link is:

[calling rpc encoded web services](http://web-gmazza.rhcloud.com/blog/entry/calling-rpc-encoded-web-services)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this really helps you, but I tackled NWS point forecasts some time ago and made my control embeddable: http://www.iontech.org/Weather

Cheers